# Upsert through Bulk API without rewrite some fields if are completed

Tags: rest-api

We have a problem when fields are fill with upsert through salesforce standar API rest using a csv because the upsert rewrite this fields, what can I do to avoid it?

Comment: So you have a PUT API service?

Comment: I use https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/api_asynch.pdf

Comment: Do you ever want those fields to be updated or are they to be locked after creation?

Comment: This fields should be blocked after create when the thrid party fire the upsert,but the user can manually to do changes